# How to grep copied content

Tags: grep, pipe

I have some content (say a paragraph or hundred odd lines from a book - they have newlines) that I have copied. How do I `grep` them? I mean is there a utility that can simply echo this content whose output then can be fed to `grep` command through a `pipe`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the content? If it is in a file 'foo' try

```
grep -E whateveryouarelookingfor foo
```

if it is in a bash variable 'bar' try

```
echo "${bar}" | grep -E whateveryouarelookingfor
```

Comment: Well, it is a multi-line content.

Comment: use sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' filename to remove all line endings from the content, then you can grep at will.